# Can all language constructs be first-class in languages with offside-rules?

Tags: python, lisp, expression, indentation, if-statement

In LISP-like languages all language constructs are first-class citizens.

Consider the following example in Dylan:

```
let x = if (c)
          foo();
        else
          bar();
        end;
```

and in LISP:

```
(setf x (if c (foo) (bar)))
```

In Python you would have to write:

```
if c:
    x = foo();
else:
    x = bar();
```

Because Python destinguishes statements and expressions.

Can all language constructs in a language which adheres to the off-side rule (has an indention-based syntax) be expressions, so that you can assign them to variables or pass them as parameters?

Comment: I'm not so sure an if expression in lisp es as simple as it may sound... it's a special form, because it's not evaluated with the same rules as a simple function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see the relation with first-classness here - you're not passing the `if` **statement** to the function, but the object it returns, which is as fully first class in python as in lisp.  However as far as having a statement/expression dichotomy, clearly it is possible: Haskell for instance has indentation-based syntax, yet as a purely functional language obviously has no statements.

I think Python's separation here has more to do with forbidding dangerous constructs like "if x=4:" etc than any syntax limitation. (Though I think it loses more than it gains by this - sometimes having the flexibility sufficient to shoot off your foot is very valuable, even if you do risk losing a few toes now and again.)

Answer (score 9):

Python has the following syntax that performs the same thing:

```
x = foo() if c else bar()
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why the OP said otherwise.You can even do: "y = foo if c else bar; x = y()" if you want to.

Comment: How would this be indented when going over several lines?